# How to get the test report of a job in Jenkins using python-jenkins

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, jenkins, python-requests

We have commands to get `last_build_number`, `get_build_console_output`, `build_job_url` etc with [python_jenkins](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). But, I want to fetch the url of the latest successful build a jenkins job that executes selenium test. Is there any way to get it with either [python-jenkins](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or any other method. Please share it to me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

See this [example](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jenkins.Jenkins.get_build_info) for getting next build number. You need to replace nexBuildNumber with lastSuccessfulBuild